# Do I need to have all the weapons for Treasure Hunter achievement in my inventory?

Tags: final-fantasy-13

I'm working on the Treasure Hunter achievement and wanted to know if I need to have all of the required items in my inventory when I talk to Bhakti, or if it is enough to have held them all at least once in the past? If I sell a tier 2 weapon, will I earn the achievement, when I talk to Bhakti?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to have possesed them at one point, else it wouldnt be fun with the crafting and all :D

Comment: I've sold all My items and weapons to buy the items that i have miss. I have a checklist but i haven't earn the achievement. I checked many Times but i had all items in game, i don't understand what's the problem

Comment: @NxA Have you crafted all the available items as well? Some items can only be obtained by crafting.

Comment: Ok, done, i forgot one item